# Como escrever uma nova linha em arquivo .txt com Node usando módulo fs

Tags: node.js, fs

Olá, estou com um problema para escrever novas linhas em um arquivo txt utilizando o módulo fs do Node. Pesquisando encontrei a função writeFile para escrever no arquivo, porém em toda execução ela gera um novo arquivo .txt,, quando na verdade eu gostaria de apenas inserir novas linhas SEM APAGAR O CONTEÚDO JÁ EXISTENTE no arquivo.

Qual a função correta para esta finalidade ?

```
fs.writeFile('senhas.txt', pass, (err) => {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('Senha salva!');
});
```

Comment: Provavelmente você vai precisar informar a [`flag:'a+'` nas opções da função](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fswritefilefile-data-options-callback) na documentação diz que o padrão é `flag:'w'` _(Abrir para escrever, se o arquivo não existir cria, se o arquivo existir limpa ele)_

Answer (score 0):

Encontrei a solução com a função appendFile da api promises do próprio módulo fs...

```
const grava= require('node:fs/promises')
grava.appendFile('senhas.txt', "\n"+pass, (err) => {
if (err) throw err;
console.log('Senha salva!');
});
```